# Netty 4 headers: Should I use static methods or instance methods?

Tags: netty

http://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/handler/codec/http/HttpHeaders.html

Netty 4 now has both static methods or instance methods to manipulate headers. For example: `HttpHeaders#get` and `HttpHeaders.getHeader`.

As I remember, the static methods have just been added recently. Is that true that from now on I should use the static methods because they are faster, and the instance methods will be deprecated in the future?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2671496/java-when-to-use-static-methods

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The static methods are there for a long time. So it not matter what you use.